# Meteor после деплоя происходит редирект на https

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, nginx, развертывание, meteor

Обычное todo Meteor + React после деплоя по [данной инструкции](http://isizov.ru/meteor-ubuntu-deploy/) на чистой ubuntu 16.04 + Nginx proxy (какие варианты только не пробовал) перенаправляет на https. Что делать не знаю. Есть наверняка простое решение, но какое?

До этого пробовал на Ubuntu 14.04, было тоже самое. Полагая что дело в старых версиях nodejs и npm обновил до 16.04.

Nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name sitename.ru www.sitename.ru;

    root /home/sitename/bundle/programs/web.browser;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/sitename.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/sitename.error.log;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    } 
}
```

Comment: проблема у вас в nginx конфиге. скиньте, посмотрим

Comment: добавил в описание

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё как я и думал - просто :)

https://github.com/meteor/todos/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=force-ssl&type=